# Wrong conversion of date-string to date

Tags: sql, oracle, to-date

When running these statements:

```
select to_date('201103270100', 'YYYYMMDDHH24MI') from dual;
select to_date('201103270130', 'YYYYMMDDHH24MI') from dual;
```

I get these results:

```
27/3/2011 1:00:00
27/3/2011 1:30:00
```

which are correct.

But when running:

```
select to_date('201103270200', 'YYYYMMDDHH24MI') from dual
```

I get a wrong hour as result

```
27/3/2011 3:00:00
```

More samples:

```
select to_date('201103270215', 'YYYYMMDDHH24MI') from dual
select to_date('201103270245', 'YYYYMMDDHH24MI') from dual
select to_date('201103270300', 'YYYYMMDDHH24MI') from dual
select to_date('201103270330', 'YYYYMMDDHH24MI') from dual

27/3/2011 3:15:00
27/3/2011 3:45:00
27/3/2011 3:00:00
27/3/2011 3:30:00
```

When the date is 20110326, I get the correct result.

This is crazy... Is Oracle SQL bullying me with this conversion?
Help is welcome!

Comment: Daylight savings ? ;)

Comment: It works right for me. See sqlfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/47e5d/3

Comment: @alfasin, thought daylight saving did not start until 29th March 2015 ;)

Comment: @PaulFrancis It's not the same day in all the countries ;)

Comment: @PaulFrancis DST started on 27th March for the year 2011

Comment: @PaulFrancis This is 2011 we're talking about. It was the 27th there ;)

Comment: @Siguza Depends on where you live in the world. For the US I think it was the 16th (at least that's what google told me). But yes, Daylight savings would be my guess as well.

Comment: SELECT dbtimezone FROM DUAL; to find out what your system's current timezone, which affects the DST rules, is.

Comment: @waka In Europe it starts on the last Sunday in March.

Comment: In Europe, in the year 2011, the day light saving was with effect from 27th March, 2011 at 2:00 AM.

Comment: @DavidAldridge, that's wrong. `DBTIMEZONE` only defines the "internal format" of `TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIMEZONE` values. Use `Select SESSIONTIMEZONE From dual;` or get timezone of database server via `select TZ_OFFSET(SYSTIMESTAMP) from dual`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is Oracle SQL bullying me with this conversion?

Oracle is too dumb to bully a developer, unless the developer tries to bully it ;-)

There can't be different outputs without any reason. In **Europe**, in the year 2011, the **day light saving** was with effect from **27th March, 2011 at 2:00 AM**. **[Source is wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summer_Time_in_Europe)**.

So, keeping in mind the day light saving, let's see the results for the datetime after **2:00 AM**:

```
SQL> SELECT to_char(to_date('201103270100', 'YYYYMMDDHH24MI'), 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM dual;

TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('20
-------------------
27/03/2011 01:00:00

SQL> SELECT to_char(to_date('201103270130', 'YYYYMMDDHH24MI'), 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM dual;

TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('20
-------------------
27/03/2011 01:30:00

SQL> SELECT to_char(to_date('201103270200', 'YYYYMMDDHH24MI'), 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM dual;

TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('20
-------------------
27/03/2011 02:00:00

SQL> SELECT to_char(to_date('201103270215', 'YYYYMMDDHH24MI'), 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM dual;

TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('20
-------------------
27/03/2011 02:15:00

SQL> SELECT to_char(to_date('201103270245', 'YYYYMMDDHH24MI'), 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM dual;

TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('20
-------------------
27/03/2011 02:45:00

SQL> SELECT to_char(to_date('201103270300', 'YYYYMMDDHH24MI'), 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM dual;

TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('20
-------------------
27/03/2011 03:00:00

SQL> SELECT to_char(to_date('201103270330', 'YYYYMMDDHH24MI'), 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM dual;

TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('20
-------------------
27/03/2011 03:30:00

SQL>
```

If your provided data and examples are correct, then this should be the reason.

So, you should see the time portion exactly at **2:00 AM** to shift to **3:00 AM**. Similarly, **2:15 AM** would be **3:15 AM**. Just **add an hour** to the time for those which are after 2:00 AM.

Comment: Ugh - I've dug myself to deep into this problem to see clear. Thanks! Strange that our source system accepts this date/time... But that's another problem.